# Embedded tweet not displaying client-side on nextjs 13 with appDir

Tags: next.js, twitter

Embedded Tweets are `html/js` snippets given by Twitter for you to just add to your html, and it loads an iframe doing everything.

When displaying a page on nextjs through server, it does display well.

However, when using the Link client side router, the snippet is displayed without loading the iframe. So there's nothing displaying. I guess it must come from how it has been loaded by nextjs. By watching at the Source tab, I saw that something was usually loaded that is not when it comes from client side : a js folder generated by the twitter script. Even preloading the twitter js script doesn't do the trick.

How could I change that ?

Answer (score 1):

By watching closely at the twitter script, widget.js, I saw this :

```js
window.twttr.widgets.load();
```

We are going to preload the script in the app, before trying to access these properties that may not exist yet.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const s = document.createElement("script");
    s.setAttribute("src", "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
    s.setAttribute("async", "true");
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  }, []);
```

Now we have access to twitter properties in window.

We are in nextJS, window can throw if used server side. So we wrap it like that :

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.twttr.widgets.load();
  }, []);
```

And the tweet loads!